# How to count the number of lines in an array with similar beginning and insert counter in a new array?

Tags: loops, perl, count

I have a text file (a sorted array of lines) where are listed the occurrences of a word form (declination) in a given text and its accordance to the initial form of the word. I'd like to modify the file so that the similar forms are counted and a new file (array) created with a given form, the number of its occurrences and the initial form.

I am writing in Perl, but i suppose it can be solved in pseudo code.

```perl
my $word1 = '';
my $word2 = '';
foreach my $line(@lines) { #read the array by lines 
  $word1 = $line;
  $word1 =~ s/(.+)WORD.+/$1/g; #the given form and initial form are separated by "WORD" word, so i put in $word1 the given form.

  if (lc $word1 ne lc $word2) { #if the given form doesn't match the previous form the line is added to a new list
    push @lines_out, $line;
    $word2 = $word1; #the used given form is $word2
  }
}
```

E.g. i have input:

```
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурганга WORD Бурган
Бурганга WORD Бурган
Бургандан WORD Бурган
Бургандан WORD Бурган
бурганнарның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
```

And i want output to be like:

```
Бурган WORD Бурган
Бурганга WORD Бурган
Бургандан WORD Бурган
бурганнарның WORD Бурган
Бурганның WORD Бурган
```

But with a count of occurrences before "WORD".

Where do i put the counter and how can i put it after the given form in a new array?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some input/output samples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) to preserve the order of words in the original file helps keep things simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/;
use feature qw/say/;
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %words, 'Tie::IxHash';

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split /\s*WORD\s*/;
  if (exists $words{$F[0]}) {
    $words{$F[0]}->[1] += 1;
  } else {
    $words{$F[0]} = [ $F[1], 1 ];
  }
}

while (my ($word1, $val) = each %words) {
  my ($word2, $count) = @$val;
  say "$word1 $count WORD $word2";
}
```

Example:

```
$ perl wordcount.pl words.txt
Бурган 8 WORD Бурган
Бурганга 2 WORD Бурган
Бургандан 2 WORD Бурган
бурганнарның 1 WORD Бурган
Бурганның 5 WORD Бурган
```

If you don't care about the order of the output, a regular hash can be used instead. Replace the `tie` line with just `my %words;`.

---

And a non-perl oneliner using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) and awk to rearrange the output:

```
datamash -Wfg 1 count 1 < words.txt | awk '{ print $1, $4, $2, $3 }'
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful Tie::IxHash, was looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));

my $fn = 'input.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;
close $fh;
my $word;
my $prev_word = undef;
my $prev_line;
my $count = 0;
my @lines_out;
for my $i (0..$#lines) {
    my $line = $lines[$i];
    $word = $line =~ s/(.+)WORD.+/$1/gr;
    $prev_line = $line if !defined $prev_line;
    $prev_word = $word if !defined $prev_word;
    if (((lc $word) ne (lc $prev_word))) {
        my $new_line = $prev_line =~ s/(WORD)/$count $1/r;
        push @lines_out, $new_line;
        $prev_word = $word;
        $prev_line = $line;
        $count = 0;
    }
    if ( $i == $#lines ) {
        $count++;
        my $new_line = $prev_line =~ s/(WORD)/$count $1/r;
        push @lines_out, $new_line;
    }
    $count++;
}
print for @lines_out;
```

**Output**:

```
Бурган 8 WORD Бурган
Бурганга 2 WORD Бурган
Бургандан 2 WORD Бурган
бурганнарның 1 WORD Бурган
Бурганның 5 WORD Бурган
```